# Qt - execute commands through plink with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, plink

I'm trying to modify a file on a server linux with the following code but it doesn't work.

```
        QProcess *pProcess = new QProcess(this);
        QProcess *pProcess2 = new QProcess(this);
        pProcess2->setStandardOutputProcess(pProcess);

        QString cmd = QString("plink.exe -ssh %1 -i root.ppk -l root tee /etc/test.txt").arg(strSensorAddress);

        pProcess2->start("echo hello");
        pProcess->start(cmd);

        pProcess->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
```

I was able to do it using a file like this :

```
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-ssh" << strSensorAddress << "-i" << "root.ppk" << "-l" << "root" << "-m" << sFileName;

    pProcess->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    pProcess->start("plink.exe", arguments);
```

With the file containing :

```
echo hello |  tee /etc/factory_test.txt
```

But since the content needs to be changed I would to not rely on a file.

I'am able to execute commands when there's only one command needed, for exemple just creating a file like this :

```
    QString cmd = QString("plink.exe -ssh %1 -i root.ppk -l root  touch test.txt").arg(strSensorAddress);

    pProcess->start(cmd);
```

But when I need to do 2 commands like `echo hello > test.txt`, I can't do it

Answer (score 0):

You can only run a process not a command with QProcess. However you can do :

```
process.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "cat file | grep string");
```

for example.

Comment: But how to do it on a remote server, so using ssh ?

Comment: don't you have bash on your serveur ?

Comment: no, and I don't start my program on the server either